# Check if JSONObject contains nested value if not put a new value

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using `Jackson 2.6.5`.

I have the following JSON:

```
{   
    "field1":
        {
            "innerField1":"innervalue"
        },

    "field2":"value"
}
```

And I read the JSON as follow:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

I want to check if my `jsonObj` contains nested value, What I'm try is:

```
if(!jsonObj.has("field1.innerField1"))//Trying to append if not exist
```

And If the value isn't exist to append it, What I'm trying is:

```
jsonObj.put("field1.innerField1","innervalue");
```

But its not worked for me (`has` always contains `false` and `put` create a new value like `field1.innerField1.value` instaed netsted value,

So how can I check if the JSON contains nested value and If not to append it?

Thanks!

Comment: check for length, if length<1{ ...append }

Comment: "create a new value like field1.innerField1.value instaed netsted value": this should give you a clear hint what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Key `field1` contains json object. so you need to read JSONObject with key `field1` and then check exist with required key.
Try with this:

```
String jsonString = "{   \n" +
            "    \"field1\":\n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "            \"innerField1\":\"innervalue\"\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    \"field2\":\"value\"\n" +
            "}";
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONObject innerJson = jsonObj.getJSONObject("field1");
    if(!innerJson.has("innerField1")){
        innerJson.put("innerField1","innervalue");
    }
```

Comment: And If I have case of "field1.innerField1.innerField2" thats isn't work for me

Comment: Your solution is good but I think I need generic solution for any nested json

Comment: @YaKo Were you able to solve this for a deeper nested json?

Answer (score 0):

Please Convert your JsonObject to string and use string.contatin method to check the given string is present on the JsonObject string or not

Ex:-

```
String jsonString = "{   \n" +
            "    \"field1\":\n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "            \"innerField1\":\"innervalue\"\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    \"field2\":\"value\"\n" +
            "}";
if(!jsonString.contain("\"innerField1\":\"innervalue\")){
//add element in json
}
```